# Netbeans auto generated GUI not showing because of the infinite loop... but I need that loop

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

This code is made using Netbeans drag and drop... and for some reason, it runs in the background. Any ideas why? Also, the answers from other questions don't quite seem to work, maybe I've done it wrong?

```
package tanks;

import java.util.Random;

public class Tanks extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Tanks() {
        initComponents();
        BrownTank();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Tanks!");
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("PMingLiU", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("◻");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("PMingLiU", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 51, 0));
        jLabel2.setText("◻");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(244, 244, 244)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(315, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 281, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(89, 89, 89))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        int speed = 3;
        if (evt.getKeyChar() == 'w') {
            jLabel1.setBounds(jLabel1.getX(), jLabel1.getY() - speed, jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight());
        }
        if (evt.getKeyChar() == 's') {
            jLabel1.setBounds(jLabel1.getX(), jLabel1.getY() + speed, jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight());
        }
        if (evt.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
            jLabel1.setBounds(jLabel1.getX() - speed, jLabel1.getY(), jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight());
        }
        if (evt.getKeyChar() == 'd') {
            jLabel1.setBounds(jLabel1.getX() + speed, jLabel1.getY(), jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight());
        }
    }                               

    public void PlayerBullet() {

    }

    public void BrownTank() {
        while (true) {
            int speed = 2;
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int Movement = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
            if (Movement == 1) {
                jLabel2.setBounds(jLabel2.getX(), jLabel2.getY() - speed, jLabel2.getWidth(), jLabel2.getHeight());
            }

            if (Movement == 2) {
                jLabel2.setBounds(jLabel2.getX(), jLabel2.getY() + speed, jLabel2.getWidth(), jLabel2.getHeight());
            }

            if (Movement == 3) {
                jLabel2.setBounds(jLabel2.getX() - speed, jLabel2.getY(), jLabel2.getWidth(), jLabel2.getHeight());
            }

            if (Movement == 4) {
                jLabel2.setBounds(jLabel2.getX() + speed, jLabel2.getY(), jLabel2.getWidth(), jLabel2.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tanks().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Create a new thread to avoid blocking the thread reserved for the UI.

Comment: how do I do that? soz but I'm a total beginner in programming

Comment: Oracle has many tutorials detailing the Java language. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html is the section dealing with concurrency.

Comment: i still don't get it. Could you help me fix my code?

Comment: I think i get it now... so a thread is basically a method?

Comment: I get the same error